# Issue while creating a job_config parameter dynamically in bigquery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to load the data via `bq_client.load_table_from_uri`. I am getting below error not sure why.
I am expecting `job_config` as below

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig( 
   schema=[bigquery.SchemaField("COL1","STRING"), 
           bigquery.SchemaField("COL2","STRING"), 
           bigquery.SchemaField("COL3","INTEGER"),
          ], 
   skip_leading_rows=1,
   source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
   field_delimiter='|',
   max_bad_records=1 
  )
```

When I hardcode the job_config its works fine but when tries to generate dynamically its gives me error .
variable1 & variable2 are static ,bigquery_final_temp variable will be generted dynamically via some other process.

Note: job_config  is hardcoded its datatype is "LoadJobConfig" but when its dynamically constructed its datatype is str. How can i convert this str datatype to "LoadJobConfig"

below is the file data,code,error

file data :

```
header|1234|2020-10-10
abc|xyz|12345
aws|gcp|1234
```

code:

```
uri = "gs://abc/sftp/test.csv"
var_delimitor = '|'
variable1 = 'bigquery.LoadJobConfig( schema=['
variable2 = '],skip_leading_rows=1,source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,field_delimiter='+var_delimitor+',max_bad_records=1 )'
bigquery_final_temp = 'bigquery.SchemaField("COL1","STRING"),bigquery.SchemaField("COL2","STRING"),bigquery.SchemaField("COL3","INTEGER"),'
job_config_2=variable1 + bigquery_final_temp
job_config_final=job_config_2 + variable2
###########load data
load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,Table_name, job_config=job_config_final
)  # Make an API request.

print('Lots of content here 5')
load_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

print('Lots of content here 6')
table = bq_client.get_table(Table_name)
print("Loaded {} rows to table {}".format(table.num_rows, Table_name))
```

error:

```
TypeError: Expected an instance of LoadJobConfig class for the job_config parameter, 
but received job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig( schema=[bigquery.SchemaField("COL1","STRING"),bigquery.SchemaField("COL2","STRING"),
bigquery.SchemaField("COL3","INTEGER"),],skip_leading_rows=1,source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,field_delimiter='|',max_bad_records=1)
```

Comment: This is resolved .  we need to create a list and append schema to it using "bigquery.SchemaField" command

Comment: Hello, if your issue has been solved, could please post it as an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that it helps future users? Overall, I understand that when you are concatenating strings for the configuration, each of the `bigquery.SchemaField` is not being instantiated, furthermore, the same happens with `bigquery.LoadJobConfig`. In order to overcome this issue, even though you can use variables dynamically, each of the SchemaField should be instantiated and then appended to the list called `schema`. You would also need to explicitly instantiate `bigquery.LoadJobConfig`